# Reference/quote request: "All of combinatorics is the representation theory of $S_n$"

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, ho.history-overview, co.combinatorics

I think I remember reading somewhere a glib (or is it deep?) quote, perhaps due to Rota?, which was something like

> "All of combinatorics is essentially [or can be reduced to?] the representation theory of the symmetric group."

Does anyone know the actual quote / who said or wrote it / a reference to it? Or even a second-hand or third-hand reference, e.g. a paper where author X says "I've heard it said that..." or "Person Y told me that Rota once said..."

(I tried Googling, but found it difficult to come up with a query that got me quotations as opposed to lots of papers on representation theory, combinatorics, or the symmetric group. The quotation may of course be in such a paper, but the results were often so numerous as to be unhelpful.)

Comment: Reminds me of a thing I just read: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/hidden/papers/Quotes/Combinatorics-quotes.htm

Comment: This seems to fail badly in the case of hungarian style combinatorics :)

Comment: The converse may be true: the representation theory of the symmetric group can be reduced to combinatorics.

Comment: Dan and Geoff: that's why I called it glib :).

Comment: Don't worry, it's fun :)
